# Haskell: how to deal with IO monad inside another IO monad?

Tags: haskell

just started learning haskell - love it after a week. At the moment going through the monads pain, not there yet but hopefully it will click.

I am trying to put together a function similar to pythons walk() but simpler.
Given a path I want to generate list of tuples. A tuple for each sub directory (lets just assume that there will be only directories). The tuple would contain path of the directory as its first element and list of files the directory contains as the second element.

I don't know if I explained it correctly but here is the code:

```
walkDir :: String -> IO [IO (FilePath, [FilePath])]
walkDir path = do
  dir <- getDirectoryContents path  
  let nd = [x | x <- dir, notElem x [".",".."]]
  return (map getcont nd)
    where
      getcont path = do
      cont <- getDirectoryContents path
      return (path,cont)
```

My concern is IO inside IO and how to deal with it?? Is it possible to cancel them out?
Is it possible to unwrap at least the internal IO? Is this kind of return normal?

I can not even print this kind of return. Do I have to create an instance of show for this to be printed correctly?

There most likely exist a similar function in some haskell library but this is for educational purpose. I want to learn. So any suggestions welcome.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Re. "My concern is IO inside IO and how to deal with it?? Is it possible to cancel them out?" -- This is _exactly what monads are all about!_ A fundamental monadic function (so fundamental you could define a monad in terms of it and `return`) is `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`. As you can see from the signature, its whole purpose is to "cancel out" that extra layer of monadness. Like dreams, monads within monads are just monads :)

Comment: Don't forget that `return` means something very different in Haskell than it does in most languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the types.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
getCont :: FilePath -> IO (FilePath, [FilePath])
nd :: [FilePath]

map getCont nd :: [IO (FilePath, FilePath)]
```

Now, at this point, the structure looks inside-out. We have `[IO a]` but we want `IO [a]`. Stop! Hoogle time. Generalizing for any ol' monad, we hoogle [[m a] -> m [a]](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Bm+a%5D+-%3E+m+%5Ba%5D). Lo and behold, `sequence` has that precise type signature. So instead of `return :: a -> m a` you should use `sequence :: [m a] -> m [a]`, like this:

```
sequence (map getCont nd)
```

Then you'll be all set. Notice that this is essentially identical to Kurt S's solution, because

```
mapM f xs = sequence (map f xs)
```

Comment: Thank you. Learned about hoogle from this one.I learned about sequence indirectly from Kurt's post when he mentioned mapM but didn't stretch my brains enough to apply it here.

Answer (score 10):

Check out [Control.Monad](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html) for `mapM`.

Then this

```
return (map getcont nd)
```

becomes

```
mapM getcont nd
```

Comment: There's also `join :: (Monad m) => m (m a) -> m a` which can help you in other times you have something like this.

Comment: Thanks guys :) That's exactly what I was looking for. I am just not deep in the monad stuff as yet. Trying to walk before crawl ...

Comment: @r.sendecky: mark this answer as solving it then so as to close this question off.